# Convergence of Matrix Series

Tags: matrices, analysis

I would just like a quick sanity check. If I have a matrix $ M $, then the series $ 1 + M + M^2 + M^3 \cdots $ converges to $ (1-M)^{-1} $ if the operator norm $ \lVert M \rVert_{\mathrm{op}} < 1$. Is it sufficient to show that each column vector $ v $ of $ M $ has norm $ \lVert v\rVert_{L^2} < 1 $?

Comment: By $1/(1-M)$ do you mean $(I-M)^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Yes, consider the norm of the image of a unit vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 \end{pmatrix}$ (this is projection to the diagonal).  Each column has norm smaller than $1$, but $1-M$ is a proper projection (hence not invertible).

---

**Added:** Let's work over $\mathbb{R}$. Give $\mathbb{R}^n$ the 1-norm and then $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ the corresponding operator norm (this is equivalent to the operator norm on $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ coming from the 2-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ since all norms on finite-dimensional vector spaces are equivalent -- so convergence questions are not affected).

There is a nice thing feature of this norm on $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Let $M = [m_1 \vert m_2 \vert \ldots \vert m_n] \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and put $C = \max(\|m_1\|_1,\ldots,\|m_n\|_1)$. Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a unit vector for the 1-norm. Then $$\| M x\|_1 = \|x_1 m_1 + \ldots x_n m_n\|_1 \leq |x_1| C + \ldots |x_n| C  = C$$
so that $\|M\| \leq C$. So, if $C <1$, then $1-M$ is invertible and the desired series gives the inverse.

Comment: Good point. I guess instead I should look at the $ L_1 $ norm of each column?

Comment: @user86178: That seems true. Hang on, I'll add something to my answer

Comment: I wonder if there is any condition with which the $L_2 $ norm will be useful. What if M is invertible?

Comment: Well, if $\| \cdot \|_1$ is one of the operator norms on $\mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$ is the norm which takes the largest 2-norm of a column, then you can work out the constant such that $\| \cdot \|_1 \leq C \| \cdot\|_2$. Then, having $\| \cdot \|_2 < \frac{1}{C}$ will suffice.